CSS Animation speed
I am new to CSS Anima


body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  margin: 0;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 14vh;
  height: 8vh;
}

.square {
  width: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
  border-radius: 0.4vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1vh;
}

.square.A {
  left: 0;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #31473A;
  -webkit-animation: moveA 6s infinite 0.25s alternate;
  animation: moveA 6s linear infinite 0.25s alternate;
}

.square.B {
  left: 3vh;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #26382E;
  -webkit-animation: moveB 6s infinite 0.5s alternate;
  animation: moveB 6s linear infinite 0.5s alternate;
}

.square.C {
  left: 6vh;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #1c2921;
  -webkit-animation: moveC 6s infinite 0.6s alternate;
  animation: moveC 6s linear infinite 0.6s alternate;
}

.square.E {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #3B5144;
  -webkit-animation: moveE 6s infinite alternate;
  animation: moveE 6s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes moveA {
  0% { top: 4vh; }
  5% { top: 6.5vh; left: 0; }
  10% { top: 6.5vh; left: 3vh; }
  15% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
}

@keyframes moveB {
  0%, 5% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
  12% { top: 1.5vh; left: 3vh; }
  20% { top: 1.5vh; left: 6vh; }
  25% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
}

@keyframes moveC {
  0%, 15% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
  25% { top: 6.5vh; left: 6vh; }
  35% { top: 6.5vh; left: 9vh; }
  40% { top: 4vh; left: 9vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 9vh; }
}

@keyframes moveE {
  0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
  10% { top: 4vh; left: 0; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 0; }
}
<div class="loader">
  <div class="square A"></div>
  <div class="square B"></div>
  <div class="square C"></div>
  <div class="square E"></div>
</div>



tion. I got this animation working but it has some issues with speed when going from left -> right the animation works as expected but in case of right -> left (because of alternate which I need) the squares move too fast. How can I fix this. My intention is that only one square moves at a time which is visible in left to right animation.
Here's my CSS for the animation.
Any help is appreciated.
I tried using different animation (ease-in-out, linear etc.) but still didn't get the intended behaviour. I also tried changing percentage of key frames but it messes up left -> right animation as well. What would be the best way to get the intended behaviour for both left -> right and right -> left?

My suggestion would be that instead of using alternate you build the left-right-left as a single animation.

If you put different times of dealy they are doing that strange animation, you should put same time in all of them, as i do below, idk if this what you were meaning but for me worked this way.


body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  /*background-color: #333;*/
  margin: 0;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 14vh;
  height: 8vh;
}

.square {
  width: 2vh;
  height: 2vh;
  border-radius: 0.4vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1vh;
}

.square.A {
  left: 0;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #31473A;
  -webkit-animation: moveA 6s infinite 0.25s alternate;
  animation: moveA 6s linear infinite 0.25s alternate;
}

.square.B {
  left: 3vh;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #26382E;
  -webkit-animation: moveB 6s infinite 0.25s alternate;
  animation: moveB 6s linear infinite 0.25s alternate;
}

.square.C {
  left: 6vh;
  top: 4vh;
  background-color: #1c2921;
  -webkit-animation: moveC 6s infinite 0.25s alternate;
  animation: moveC 6s linear infinite 0.25s alternate;
}

.square.E {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #3B5144;
  -webkit-animation: moveE 6s infinite alternate;
  animation: moveE 6s linear infinite 0.25s alternate;
}

@keyframes moveA {
  0% { top: 4vh; }
  5% { top: 6.5vh; left: 0; }
  10% { top: 6.5vh; left: 3vh; }
  15% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
}

@keyframes moveB {
  0%, 5% { top: 4vh; left: 3vh; }
  12% { top: 1.5vh; left: 3vh; }
  20% { top: 1.5vh; left: 6vh; }
  25% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
}

@keyframes moveC {
  0%, 15% { top: 4vh; left: 6vh; }
  25% { top: 6.5vh; left: 6vh; }
  35% { top: 6.5vh; left: 9vh; }
  40% { top: 4vh; left: 9vh; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 9vh; }
}

@keyframes moveE {
  0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
  10% { top: 4vh; left: 0; }
  100% { top: 4vh; left: 0; }
}
<div class="loader">
        <div class="square A"></div>
        <div class="square B"></div>
        <div class="square C"></div>
        <div class="square E"></div>
    </div>




The answer is somewhat unclear and contains grammatical errors. Please clarify what you mean by 'different times of dealy' and ensure the explanation is coherent. Also, consider explaining why the same time should be used.
